# How to avoid CSS conflicts inside React components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a React project which has two pages and each page has its own css file.

```
Page1.jsx -> Page1.css
Page2.jsx -> Page2.css
```

Each css file is only included in its corresponding jsx file. Both css files share similar class names (example: `column`, `image-place`, etc.). The problem is that `Page1` is affected by `Page2`'s CSS file.

I am not expert in front-end technologies. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using create-react-app?

If so, use css-modules instead https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/

> CSS Modules allows the scoping of CSS by automatically creating a
> unique classname

```js
//Page1.jsx
import React from 'react';
import styles from './page1.module.css'; // Import css modules stylesheet as styles

export const Page1 = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.column}>page1</div>
  )
}
```

```css
/* page1.module.scss */
.column {
  color: red
}
```

```js
//Page2.jsx
import React from 'react';
import styles from './page2.module.css'; // Import css modules stylesheet as styles

export const Page2 = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.column}>page2</div>
  )
}
```

```css
/* page2.module.scss */
.column {
  color: green
}
```

If you want to combine them with normal or external css class (bootstrap, tailwind, etc), try this:

```js
<div className={`${styles.column} overflow-auto`}>page1</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems that it is working. I have a new issues now if you can help. I used to have className="column overflow-auto" and overflow-auto is from bootstrap. How to combine them?

Comment: sure, I'll add that to the answer

Comment: answer edited, hope it helped!

Answer (score 1):

A possible way to avoid conflicts is to use [Sass](https://sass-lang.com). You can set it up by typing in your `react` app folder `terminal`:

```js
npm i sass --save-dev
```

Then transform all `.css` files to `.scss`. Add a unique `class` on the top level wrapper of each page, for example :

```js
retrun (<div className = "pageOne">
  <img src = "/myImage" className = "image-place"/>
</div>)
```

And finally your styles will look like this :

```css
.pageOne {

  .image-place {
    width:200px
  }
  
  .column {
    width:200px
  }
  
}
```

This way, you would have one unique `class` at the top level wrapper, and as many as `class` that have the same name in them.

Comment: couldn't this be done without scss ?